# Django_tables2 : using bootstrap in django-tables2

Tags: python, django, bootstrap-4, django-views, django-tables2

If I want to use Bootstrap in django-tables2 what should I do?
Where I should write `DJANGO_TABLES2_TEMPLATE = 'django_tables2/bootstrap4.html'`

If I want to use bootstrap5 what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Create your own template file and specify that in the settings instead.

You need to make it a copy but with bootstrap5 elements

You specify the template in `settings.py`